# How can I use removeFirst function in initialization a String instead of updating a String

Tags: swift

I need to use **removeFirst** function but I cannot use it for initialization a String and I have to update the String with that function, do we have another version or even a custom way of doing this? I just need to have `let` and no need to `var`.

```
func test1(value: String) {
    
    var newValue: String = value
    
    newValue.removeFirst()
    
    print(newValue)
    
}


func test2(value: String) {

    let newValue: String = value.removeFirst()  // I want this to work!

    print(newValue)

}
```

use case:

```
test1(value: "?new Value")

test2(value: "?new Value")
```

Comment: `String(value.dropFirst())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are using `removeFirst()`, removes the first element and returns it. Inside your function you are applying it to a string, and not doing anything with the result. The actual string is unchanged. I'm surprised that Xcode didn't raise a warning about this.

What you actually want to do is to use a function that returns the string *without* the first character. So something like-

```swift
func test1(value: String) {
    print(value.dropFirst())

test1(value: "?new Value") // prints "new Value"
}
```

You should be careful though. `dropFirst()` doesn't return a `String`, it returns a `SubString`, which the `print` function can happily deal with. If you want to return a string, you need to create one:

```swift
func test1(value: String) -> String {
    String(value.dropFirst())
}

print(test1(value: "?new Value")) // prints "new Value"
```

Which is the reason why this line of yours doesn't work:

```swift
let newValue: String = value.removeFirst()  // I want this to work!
```

You are declaring the type of newValue to be `String`, but the method returns a `Character` You can't coerce types like this. Not only that.

What you want to do is

```swift
let newValue = String(value.dropFirst())
```

Which will make a `String` out of the `SubString`, rather than trying to coerce a `Character` into a `String`

Comment: what is SubString for? why we need SubString?

Comment: **but the method returns a SubString** ??? No `removeFirst` method returns the first `Element` of the collection in this case a `Character`
 !!!

Comment: @user in most cases there is no need to initialize a new String from a SubString. Keep it as a substring whenever possible.